# The results of the logical operations & and | with NA in terra do not agree with those of R-base?

Tags: raster, logical-operators, terra

The following code shows that `terra` does not interpret `NA | TRUE` and `NA & FALSE` in the same way as `R-base` does. With `terra`, the result is `NA` in both cases. With `R-base`, the results are `TRUE` and `FALSE`, respectively. I understand that both alternatives are acceptable choices for a programming language. But it can be a real trap, even for experienced users, when a package behaves differently from `R-base` for such low-level operations as `&` and `|`. I looked in the documentation to see if this was mentioned anywhere, and I couldn't find it. If this is indeed the case, it might be useful to indicate this somewhere. But maybe I'm wrong. Or that there's a strong reason for having made this choice for `terra` rasters?

```
     vals1 <- rep(c(NA,FALSE,TRUE),each=3)
     vals2 <- rep(c(NA,FALSE,TRUE),3)
     r1 <- rast(nrows=3, ncols=3, vals=vals1)
     r2 <- rast(nrows=3, ncols=3, vals=vals2)
     Or <- r1 | r2
     And <- r1 & r2
     data.frame(r1=values(r1,mat=FALSE),r2=values(r2,mat=FALSE),"r1 or r2 (terra)"=values(Or,mat=FALSE),"r1 or r2 (R)"=vals1|vals2)
          
#         r1    r2 r1.or.r2..terra. r1.or.r2..R.
#    1    NA    NA               NA           NA
#    2    NA FALSE               NA           NA
#    3    NA  TRUE               NA         TRUE
#    4 FALSE    NA               NA           NA
#    5 FALSE FALSE            FALSE        FALSE
#    6 FALSE  TRUE             TRUE         TRUE
#    7  TRUE    NA               NA         TRUE
#    8  TRUE FALSE             TRUE         TRUE
#    9  TRUE  TRUE             TRUE         TRUE
    
    data.frame(r1=values(r1,mat=FALSE),r2=values(r2,mat=FALSE),"r1 and r2 (terra)"=values(And,mat=FALSE),"r1 and r2 (R)"=vals1 & vals2)
    
#         r1    r2 r1.and.r2..terra. r1.and.r2..R.
#    1    NA    NA                NA            NA
#    2    NA FALSE                NA         FALSE
#    3    NA  TRUE                NA            NA
#    4 FALSE    NA                NA         FALSE
#    5 FALSE FALSE             FALSE         FALSE
#    6 FALSE  TRUE             FALSE         FALSE
#    7  TRUE    NA                NA            NA
#    8  TRUE FALSE             FALSE         FALSE
#    9  TRUE  TRUE              TRUE          TRUE
```

Comment: Isn't this fixed in the dev version? https://github.com/rspatial/terra/issues/1316